# $ is undefined but loading jQuery twice fixes it

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery preloader that is loaded in my html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict()(function($){
            $(".view").preloader();
            $(".flexslider").preloader();
            });
</script>
```

My jquery.preloader.js

```
// JavaScript Document
$.fn.preloader = function(options){

    var defaults = {
                     delay:200,
                     preload_parent:"a",
                     check_timer:300,
                     ondone:function(){ },
                     oneachload:function(image){  },
                     fadein:500 
                    };

    // variables declaration and precaching images and parent container
     var options = $.extend(defaults, options),
     root = $(this) , images = root.find("img").css({"visibility":"hidden",opacity:0}) ,  timer ,  counter = 0, i=0 , checkFlag = [] , delaySum = options.delay ,

     init = function(){

        timer = setInterval(function(){

            if(counter>=checkFlag.length)
            {
            clearInterval(timer);
            options.ondone();
            return;
            }

            for(i=0;i<images.length;i++)
            {
                if(images[i].complete==true)
                {
                    if(checkFlag[i]==false)
                    {
                        checkFlag[i] = true;
                        options.oneachload(images[i]);
                        counter++;

                        delaySum = delaySum + options.delay;
                    }

                    $(images[i]).css("visibility","visible").delay(delaySum).animate({opacity:1},options.fadein,
                    function(){ $(this).parent().removeClass("preloader");   });




                }
            }

            },options.check_timer) 


         } ;

    images.each(function(){

        if($(this).parent(options.preload_parent).length==0)
        $(this).wrap("<a class='preloader' />");
        else
        $(this).parent().addClass("preloader");

        checkFlag[i++] = false;


        }); 
    images = $.makeArray(images); 


    var icon = jQuery("<img />",{

        id : 'loadingicon' ,
        src : '/assets/images/front/spinner.gif'

        }).hide().appendTo("body");



    timer = setInterval(function(){

        if(icon[0].complete==true)
        {
            clearInterval(timer);
            init();
             icon.remove();
            return;
        }

        },100);

    }
```

But when I run this, I get a "$ is undefined" and points to this line:

```
var options = $.extend(defaults, options),
```

But here's the weird thing - if I load jQuery 1.7.2 TWICE in my html file - the error goes away, and everything works as expected (including the preloader).

**Question:** how do I fix this, so I dont need to load jQuery twice to make this work??

Comment: Are you sure you are loading jQuery before you load the other scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

preloader.js should be in a ready block.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.preloader = function(options) {
        // your code here.
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: sorry - which bit exactly? I'm a bit confused?

Comment: @Laurencei I've edited the answer slightly to help you identify which code goes inside there

Answer (score 2):

You're executing the `noConflict` instruction, which makes jQuery rebind `$` to its original value (normally `undefined`). Remove `.noConflict()`. Alternately, rewrite `$.extend` into `jQuery.extend` (outside the no-conflict mode, `$` is just a shorthand synonym for `jQuery`), `$(this)` into `jQuery(this)`, etc.

Comment: if I change "jQuery.noConflict()(function($)" to "jQuery.(function($)" I get a new error:    XML filter is applied to non-XML value (function (a, b) {return new e.fn.init(a, b, h);})  ?

Comment: You haven't posted the whole error message so I really don't know what it refers to, but the line should be `jQuery(function() {...})` or equivalently `$(function() {...})` (without the dot). Since you don't engage the no-conflict mode, you can also see that it is also not necessary to receive `$` as an argument to the callback.

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues:

1. You have to wait for the DOM to be ready before referencing elements in it.  If the code you provided is not at the end of the body tag, then you need to put your code in a `document.ready` block.
2. When you use `jQuery.noConflict()`, you can no longer use `$` to reference `jQuery`.  You must instead use the symbol `jQuery`.
3. If you want to use `$` again, you can pass in `jQuery` to a self executing function block that will assign `jQuery` to the `$` symbol inside the function block which will allow you to use it there, but not interfere with any other code.

This is what I would suggest:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    (function($){
        // you can now use $ here as a reference to jQuery 
        // again inside this function
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".view").preloader();
            $(".flexslider").preloader();
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```